# Разбить массив и присвоить значение каждому PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив и он разбивается на целые числа 1 или 0

```
$comp = 1;
$rating = "1 0 1 0 1 0 0"
$inf_rating= explode(" ", $rating);
```

Затем, каждому числу присваивается какое-то значение после сравнения с переменной `$comp`, я написал это таким безобразным способом -

```
if ($inf_rating[1] == $comp) { echo 'Истина'; } else { echo 'Ложь'; }
if ($inf_rating[2] == $comp) { echo 'Истина'; } else { echo 'Ложь'; }
if ($inf_rating[3] == $comp) { echo 'Истина'; } else { echo 'Ложь'; }
if ($inf_rating[4] == $comp) { echo 'Истина'; } else { echo 'Ложь'; }
if ($inf_rating[5] == $comp) { echo 'Истина'; } else { echo 'Ложь'; }
if ($inf_rating[6] == $comp) { echo 'Истина'; } else { echo 'Ложь'; }
if ($inf_rating[7] == $comp) { echo 'Истина'; } else { echo 'Ложь'; }
```

В таком случае я получаю то, что мне нужно в таком виде -

```
Истина
Ложь
Истина
Ложь
Истина
Ложь
Ложь
```

Вопрос в следующем, как оптимизировать эту громоздкую конструкцию в каую-то более универсальную, в том смысле если чисел будет не 7, а 1000, например...? Спасибо.

Comment: а откуда вы берете значения, с которыми сравниваете? в даном случае `1 0 1 1 1` ? и эти `$inf_rating` и `$count_rating`   это вообще одно и тоже, или это наоброт сравниваемые величины?

Comment: @teran я извиняюсь, `$count_rating` старая переменная (забыл исправить) на месте этой переменной должна быть `$inf_rating`, исправил в посте.

Comment: ок, дак а логика сравнения то далее кака? первый элемент вы сраниваете с 1, второй с нулем, далее все опять с 1й. откуда знать, с чем надо сравнивать?

Comment: @teran Логика такова - можно сравнивать либо с 1 либо с 0 без разницы, можно задать переменную `$comp = 1;` и все результаты массива сравнить с этой переменной, итог может быть любым, мне важно знать метод сокращения этого перебора от 1 до 5 (или больше...). Как я себе представляю это - мы даем функции 1 и число из массива, а она нам возвращает результат, этот результат нужно циклом вывести где-то и получить значения в виде Истина, Ложь, Истина и.т.д

Answer (score 1):

Используйте цикл, в данном случае ввиду того что вы используете массив, то foreach (http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1):

Можно пройтись по массиву функцией [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php
foreach($array as $value) {
    if ($value == 1) {
        echo 'Истина';
    } else {
        echo 'Ложь';
    }
}
```

Comment: `echo $value ? 'Истина' : 'Ложь';` - так короче

Comment: можно и тернарный оператор использовать, если действительно требуется просто вывести))

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov, его проще использовать и не просто для вывода

Comment: а ничего что там не всегда с `1` сравнивается?

Comment: @teran, сей хитрый алгоритм не в силах мы понять. Особенно по примеру приведённому автором. Быть может был бы ответ другим, владея мы мыслями автора.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение -

Будем сравнивать с единицей каждое значение массива `$rating`

```
$comp = 0;
$rating = "1 0 1 0 1 0 0"
$inf_rating= explode(" ", $rating);
$count_lines = count($inf_rating);
```

Создаем цикл -

```
while ($comp <= $count_lines-1) 
{
    echo ($inf_rating[$comp] == 1) ? 'Истина' : 'Ложь';
    $comp++;
}
```

Результат выполнения -

```
Истина
Ложь
Истина
Ложь
Истина
Ложь
Ложь
```